# Convert image file to float array in Python

Tags: python

How can I convert an image to an array of float numbers?
img = cv2.imread('img.png')

and now convert img to float so I get for
print(img[0,0]) something like "[ 4.0 2.0 0.0] instead of [4 2 0]

Do you have an idea? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the list of the integers to list of floats as `[float(i) for i in values]` with list comprehension.

An other option is to convert the `img` variable as `numpy.ndarray` to an other `numpy.ndarray` which contains `float` values:

`img = img.astype(float)`

After this assignment the results will contain float values.

Comment: This answer needs an update. This is no longer working in Python 3

Comment: This works for me with Python 3. You might have to do `img = img.astype(float)/255` if you want to convert integer values from 0 to 255 to a float in the range 0 to 1.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use Skimage's img_to_float() function.

```
image = io.imread('imagefilepath')
image = skimage.img_as_float(image)
```