# Value Error: could not convert string to float: '<' when creating CNN-LSTM with character embedding

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I've been trying to train a Deep Learning model to learn the SVG-code of an image from looking at the .png image (64x64x3) corresponding to that SVG-code. I've been trying to do this using a Conv2D model (for the png's), and a RNN (for the SVG sequences). When training the model, it gives the following error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '<'`.

I don't really understand why my model wants to turn those string characters into floats.

The possible characters in the SVG are: `['<', '?', 'x', 'm', 'l', ' ', 'v', 'e', 'r', 's', 'i', 'o', 'n', '=', '"', '1', '.', '0', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'u', 't', 'f', '-', '8', '>', '\n', 'b', 'a', 'P', 'h', '6', '4', 'w', 'p', ':', '/', '3', '2', 'k', '9', 'y', '5', 'q']`

The longest SVG code is 821 characters long. I have 48000 instances.

```
# Partitioning training and validation data

print('Loading data...')
x_train, x_test = train_test_split(X, test_size=1/10, random_state=999)
y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Y, test_size=1/10, random_state=999)

# Padding

print('Pad sequences')
y_train = sequence.pad_sequences(y_train, dtype=str, maxlen=821, value="0")
y_test = sequence.pad_sequences(y_test, dtype=str, maxlen=821, value="0")

# Partial Image model

inputA = Input(shape=(64, 64, 3))
A = Conv2D (16, kernel_size = (3,3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(inputA)
A = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='valid')(A)
A = Conv2D (8, kernel_size = (3,3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(A)
A = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='valid')(A)

A = Flatten () (A)

A = Dropout(0.5)(A)
A = Dense(256, activation='relu')(A)

# Partial SVG code model
inputB = Input(shape=(820,))
B = Embedding(45, 16, mask_zero=True)(inputB)
B = Dropout(0.5)(B)
B = LSTM(256, return_sequences = False)(B)


# Decoder model
decoder1 = add([A, B])
decoder2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(decoder1)
outputs = Dense(820, activation='softmax')(decoder2)

# Merge two input models
model = Model(inputs=[inputA, inputB], outputs=outputs)
model.compile (loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics = ['accuracy'])



print('Train...')
history = model.fit([x_train, y_train[:, :-1]], y_train[:, 1:],
                    batch_size=128,
                    epochs=20,
                    verbose=2)
```

Any advice on how to get my code working would be great!
Thanks!

Comment: The CNN expects your training data to be an array of floats with color values, not a list of letters. See [Convert image file to float array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43438653/convert-image-file-to-float-array-in-python) or one-hot encoding

Comment: I'm trying to feed the characters into the Embedding and LSTM layer, and the image into the Conv2D layer. It shouldn't have to be an array of floats then right?